# Selenium VBA test case as a Function

Tags: vba, selenium

I am trying do divide my test cases as a function in Selenium VBA using Excel. My first step is to login. I made login as a function for example

```
Public Sub test()

     'my main program is here

     'First step login

      Login()

End sub

Function Login()
     ' Open Firefox command
     ' my commands here
     ' 
End function
```

what happens is whenever I call Login() and when the function ends, It Closes the browser(in this case Mozilla firefox).

Answer (score 2):

The browser is automatically disposed once the variable of the driver is out of scope. For further information, I invite you to have a look at the official documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/141693

Here is an example with a local instance of the driver:

```
Private Assert As New Assert

Sub Main()
    Dim drv As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
    drv.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"

    Call ClickLogo(drv)

    drv.Quit
End Sub

Sub ClickLogo(drv As WebDriver)
    drv.FindElementByCss("#hlogo").Click
End Sub
```

And another example with a global instance of the driver:

```
Private Assert As New Assert
Private drv As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver

Sub ProcMain()
    drv.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"
    Call ClickLogo
    drv.Quit
End Sub

Sub ClickLogo()
    drv.FindElementByCss("#hlogo").Click
End Sub
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above examples:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Answer (score 0):

Dim your selenium webdriver before the start of your sub, this will allow the webdriver instance to run outside of the 'scope' of your main sub, then use driver.quit to kill the instance at the end of your program